# Scala IDE for .NET Developers

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, scala-ide

I write C# commerically and I am using Scala IDE ( Eclipse) at home. I want to be able to structure my project so I have a play component (.NET equivalent Assembly / VS Project) and another component which is the Core (Model, Services etc)

How do I do this in the Java / Scala world with Jars etc. How do I structure this in eclipse to get these results?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Scala IDE point of view, there are 2 possibilities:

- the sbt build contains 2 projects, the core one and the play one. Using `eclipse` from the sbt prompt will generate the correct Eclipse configuration file, and the 2 projects will be linked when imported in the workspace.
- there are 2 sbt builds, each containing one project. The `eclipse` sbt command will generate independent project configurations. After importing the projects in the workspace, the `Java build path` (in the project properties) will have to be tweaked to make one project depend on the other. (quick tip: make sure to select the dependencies you need in the `Order and Export` tab).

If you set it up with 2 sbt builds, you will likely need to publish the core locally, and add it as a dependency in the play build.

I will let others chime in about configuring multi-projects in one sbt build.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you use maven. If you do, you would create a project for the play component which has a dependency on the core component, which is another maven project.

If you don't wanna learn maven because you want only a fast solution, create two separate java projects and in the project properties of the play component go to the "build path">projects tab and add the other project (core) there, this will also create a workspace dependency

Comment: I am using eclipse with SBT. Any comments?

Comment: i don't know SBT, but if you don't use maven then just do what I said in the second paragraph. That way is generic to eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If it is a play project, you can just generate the eclipse project by using 'eclipse' command in the play console, and just import the project.